# A question about the product of two ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

In my algebra textbook appear the following:

> If $I$ and $J$ are ideals, then $I$ and $J$ are both subsets of $I+J$ . But by the absorption property, $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$.

The first part is clear to me. But the last part is not clear to me, I can't see exactly why. On the other hand, when are they equal? Any examples?

Comment: As you are looking to know as to why $I \cdot J \subseteq I \cap J$

Comment: I was seeing how the absorption property worked in $I$ and $J$. but I didn't see how to relate it to what I wanted to know. Alex's response was very timely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $I,J$ be ideals of a commutative unital ring $R$.

The elements of $IJ$ are finite sums of the form $\sum x_ky_k$ where the $x_k\in I$ and the $y_k\in J$. Since $I$ and $J$ are ideals, in particular for any $r\in R$ and $i\in I$ it holds that $ri\in I$. In particular, it is then true that $x_ky_k\in J$ and $y_kx_k\in I$, i.e. $x_ky_k\in I\cap J$ for each $k$. Since this was an arbitrary element of $IJ$ it follows that $IJ\subseteq I\cap J$.

You can show that whenever $I,J$ are coprime, i.e. $I+J= R$, that $IJ=I\cap J$.
$$\begin{align}I\cap J&\subseteq(I\cap J)R\\&=(I\cap J)(I+J)\\&=(I\cap J)I+ (I\cap J)J\\&\subseteq IJ+ IJ=IJ\end{align},$$
and so in the case that $I,J$ are coprime, these two inclusions yield $IJ= I\cap J$.

---

For a non-example of equality, let $k$ be a field, and let $R=k[x,y]$. Consider the ideals $I=(x)$ and $J=(xy)$. We have $IJ=(x^2y)$ and $I\cap J =(xy)$.

Also to see that coprimality is sufficient, but not necessary for equality, consider $I=(x)$ and $J=(y)$, where $IJ=(xy)$ and $I\cap J=(xy)$, and yet $I+J =(x,y)\ne R$.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer already answers the first part by using the explicit description of $IJ$. Another way is the following:
Recall that $IJ$ is the ideal *generated* by the set of products, i.e., by the set $P = \{ij : i \in I,\ j \in J\}$.
In other words, $IJ$ is the smallest ideal that contains $P$. To show that $IJ \subset I \cap J$, it suffices to show that $P \subset I \cap J$.

*That*, now follows from the absorption property of ideals.
[Given $ij \in P$ (where $i \in I$ and $j \in J$), it is in $I$ because $i \in I$ and $j \in R$. Similarly, it is in $J$ because $j \in J$ and $i \in R$.]

---

The other answer has given some nice examples as well. Note that in general, it is easy to find generators of $I + J$ and $IJ$. Indeed, if $I = (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $J = (b_1, \ldots, b_m)$, then we have
\begin{align}
I + J &= (a_1, \ldots, a_n, b_1, \ldots, b_m) \\ 
IJ &= (a_i b_j : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n, \ 1 \leqslant j \leqslant m).
\end{align}
(The analogous statement holds even if the generating sets chosen for $I$ and $J$ are infinite.)

However, $I \cap J$, in general, has no simple set of generators. But in the case of polynomial rings and *monomial* ideals, we do have something better.
With the notations as earlier, assume that $R = k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, where $k$ is a field, and assume that each $a_i$ and $b_j$ is a monomial. Then, we have
$$I \cap J = (\operatorname{lcm}(a_i, b_j) : 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n, \ 1 \leqslant j \leqslant m).$$
This gives an idea as to how one can generate the examples as in the other answer.